# How to clean/erase structural block in Magento CE?

Tags: magento

I'm new to Magento :)

is it possible to clean structural block and start adding content blocks from scratch?

for example in my_package/my_theme/layout/local.xml
I would like to have something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>
        <remove name="header" />
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: This isn't a great idea, you may find a lot of issues if you remove key blocks. What task are you actually trying to achieve, there may be a better way.

Comment: I have store design, totally different from the magento's.  So I need to build everything from scratch.  But I'm not sure how to effectively achieve this.

Comment: what is you actual requiremnt

Comment: I have store design, totally different from the magento's. So I need to build everything from scratch. But I'm not sure how to effectively achieve this.

Comment: You're looking for a blank or boilerplate theme, try this question. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/959/magento-boilerplate-blank-skeleton-naked-themes-for-theme-development

Answer (score 1):

The default Magento blank theme would be worthwhile to start working off of,  I built this site based from the blank theme. 
http://frea.licenseschool.com/
This site almost does not resemble Magento in any way.
Then include any overrides you need to the base theme in your own package and theme.
Base theme includes very little and can work quite well to build from.